# Showing Item context menu in custom Javascript page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have created a Javascript page, that uses some REST calls to query a list (actually several lists) and shows some highly customized output. All this is working quite good. My final requirement is, that I want to give the user a link to the Item context menu:

[image]

The question is: What Javascript code should I use to create such a link, given that I "only" have the list id and the item id?

Regards
Leif

Comment: Use F12 Dev console to trace what ``OpenCalloutAndSelectItem`` from core.js does

Answer (score 0):

You can use below URL to link to the Item context menu

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID="+ItemID
```

For ListName you can use Title of list from the data you are receiving through rest call.

Comment: Hi Ankitkumar, this gives me a link to the form - not the actual Item Menu (the "..." menu). I just updated the initial question with an image to make it clearer what I need :-)